# Rename Files To Fit Standard

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

In a personnel folder there are files regarding coaching for employees that were created by the persons supervisor.  The naming convention for these files **ALWAYS** should be like

```
Supervisorname.SXXEXX.NameOfIssue.doc
```

So a breakdown further:

- Supervisorname = Bob Godfrey
- SXX = stipulation number (always 2 digits ranges from 01 - 99, but not all numbers are used)
- EXX = employee number (always 2 digits, we have not hit the point where we need to move to 3 digits or to a diff prefix other than E yet....)

So a sample name would be `Bob Godfrey.S48E99.Issue With Blue.doc` - however, since some supervisors did not follow the rules there are files without the `.` seperator, we have files that look like

```
Bob Godfrey - S48E99 - Issue With Blue.doc
Bob Godfrey X S48E99 - Issue With Blue.doc
Bob Godfrey S48E99 - Issue With Blue.doc
```

For normalization purposes, (and for me not to pull my hair out in the process) I tried to use the below syntax to grab these outliers and rename them (there are roughly 300) now while this seems to execute as it should, the files are not renamed.

What do I need to change to get these files renamed accordingly?

```
Get-ChildItem -Path R:\Personnel\ -Filter *.doc |
    Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName.Replace(" - ", ".") + $_.Extension } -Verbose

Get-ChildItem -Path R:\Personnel\ -Filter *.doc |
    Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName.Replace(" X ", ".") + $_.Extension } -Verbose
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken - shouldn't the example line have a dot between SXX and EXX?

Comment: @LotPings - No there should not be a dot between SXX and EXX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$Pattern=[RegEx]'^([^-.]+?)(\.| | X | - )(S\d{2})\.*(E\d{2,3})(\.| - )([^\.]+)(\.doc)$'
$Replace='$1.$3.$4.$6$7'
GCI -Path R:\Personnel\ -Filter *.doc | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace $Pattern,$Replace}
```

The `$Pattern` has 7 groups

1. group for supervisor `([^-.]+?)` neg.class, no - or dot at least one char, lazy
2. group for the divider `(\.| | X | - )` either a dot or space or `x` or `-`
3. group for stipulation number `(S\d{2})` S and 2 digits (maybe followed by a dot) `\.*`
4. group employee number `(E\d{2,3})` E and two or three digits
5. group divider `(\.| - )` either a dot or `-`
6. group issue `([^\.]+)` neg.class everything but a dot at least one char
7. group the extension `(\.doc)` anchored at the end of the line `$`

Comment: How do I add a path to this syntax?

Comment: @BellHopByDayAmetuerCoderByNigh you could prior `Set-Location` or use `Pushd`, but I include your original command.

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression replacement to center your matches around the stipulation/employee number part of the filename:

```
Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace ' (?:[-X] )?(S\d\dE\d\d)(?: [-X])? ', '.$1.' }
```

Comment: I think that won't match the single space in front of the stipulation number.

Comment: How do I add the path to this syntax?

Comment: @LotPings You're right. I forgot to make the non-capturing groups optional. Fixed.

Comment: @BellHopByDayAmetuerCoderByNigh You don't. Why would you want to?